# What have I done wrong with my matrices to make this quad render like this?

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, lwjgl

I am attempting to render a Quad in 3D using OpenGL 3.2

When viewing the quad directly on it looks fairly normal
[image]

However when I look to the side so that the quad is not in the centre of the screen it distorts like so
[image]

I have a feeling that this is to do with how I deal with the matrices

Here is the multiplication method in my matrix class

```
public Matrix4f mul(Matrix4f m4f) {
    float[][] m = new float[4][4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            float mij = 0;
            for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                mij += this.m[k][j] * m4f.m[i][k];
            }
            m[i][j] = mij;
        }
    }
    this.m = m;
    return this;
```

And here is where I compute the view matrix

```
public Matrix4f getViewMatrix() {
    Matrix4f m = Matrix4f.getNewIdentityMatrix();
    m.mul(Matrix4f.getNewRotationMatrix(-Math.toRadians(rotation.x), -Math.toRadians(rotation.y), 0));
    m.mul(Matrix4f.getNewTranslationMatrix(-pos.x, -pos.y, -pos.z));

    return m;
}
```

Here is how I use the matrices in the vertex shader

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position = proj * modelview * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

I know that my perspective projection matrix works as intended.

Comment: Sure looks like a perspective distortion. Are you sure, that you do not create a perspective projection with a very large field of view angle?
Also, check that your modelview is orthonormal.
(The mul code looks okay at a first glance)

Comment: @Thomas God I feel stupid... Yeah just a large fov :|